# lapply to assign labels

Tags: r, lapply

I'm having trouble using lapply to change the labels of a data table/frame

```
   dt<-data.table(a=1:4,b=letters[1:5],c=5:9)
   > label(dt)
     a  b  c 
     "" "" "" 
   > lapply(c("a","b","c"),function(x) label(dt$x)="aaa")
                                          Show Traceback
                                          Rerun with Debug
     Error in attr(x, "label") <- value : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

Why is it not working? If I do it outside of `lapply` the `label(dt$a)="aaa"` works

Comment: i prefer a `for` loop for such things: `for(i in c("a","b","c")) Hmisc::label(dt[[i]]) <- "aaa"`

Comment: Do not use dt$x inside functions. You could try `dt[[x]]`

Comment: I tried dt[[x]], error is gone but the labels are not retained :

Comment: `> sapply(c("a","b","c"),function(x) label(dt[[x]])="aaa")`
        ` a     b     c `
       `"aaa" "aaa" "aaa" `
     ` > label(dt)`
       `  a  b  c `
        `"" "" ""`

Comment: for loop worked - Thanks!

Comment: @user20650 You could post that as a solution

Answer (score 2):

Use `dt[[x]]` instead of `dt$x`. It's using x as a literal.

Also as the function is not returning a value it is easier to use an explicit loop (rather than `sapply` or `lapply`)

```
for(i in c("a","b","c")) {
        Hmisc::label(dt[[i]]) <- "aaa"
}
```